# Minecraft Big Dig Pack - No Hostile Mobs Spawning

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-technic-pack

I am playing the Big Dig mod pack using the Technic Platform. Up until about a day ago, my world was pretty normal - creepers, slimes, etc. However, now it seems that I don't have any hostile mobs spawning.

I think it might have to do with when I fell through the bottom of the world after going too deep into multiple Dimensional Doors...when I came out, I was 20+ kilometers from home in the middle of the ocean, where I found a huge dungeon full of spawners. I raided the dungeon for awhile and then spent a long time trekking back to my base.

Are there any "quick fixes" I should try to see if I can get mobs to start spawning again? Could it be the "Mob Extinction" issue? What should I do?

EDITED TO ADD: I think I have at least a partial confirmation that the issue has to do with spawn limits, etc. I traveled to the Nether last night for some Nether stuff, and there were Ghasts a-plenty, along with Zombie Pigmen and Blazes. Also, monster *spawners* still work in the Overworld - it just seems that there's no random spawns.

Comment: check your difficulty setting under options

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry, didn't mention it, but yes, I am not on peaceful, I'm on normal.

Comment: check if `/gamerule doMobSpawning` shows `true`

Comment: Every time I read the title to this question, I see profanity.  I swear it's a subliminal message or something...

Comment: @AlvinWong Yes, doMobSpawning is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was related to the Dimensional Doors mod, and it is now resolved with newer versions (I am running 1.3.2 with my install of Big Dig and it is all fine, and mobs are back).

Reference can be found [here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1650007-151universal-dimensional-doors-v133-physics-what-physics/page__st__900#entry21724643).

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is that you have some mods installed that prevent mob de-spawning, and the dungeon that you raided probably had lots of mobs in there, not leaving room for any more to spawn.

Comment: Is there a way for me to manually whack all the mobs, so that I could get back to normal spawning?

Comment: Shouldn't that be irrelevant once those chunks are unloaded?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I think the user is saying that there's some kind of issue because I have mods that prevent / alter the chunk and spawning code?

Comment: You could switch to peaceful and then back to normal or hard (whichever you're playing on).  This will effectively kill all hostile mobs.

Comment: You can also take a look at [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/21541/1351) from a while ago.

Answer (score 1):

Trolling the forums I found other people having the same issue. I believe it has something to do with the dimensional doors mod. After people come back from Limbo it seems to be shutting off the overworld mobs.

Comment: Yes, I think that this must be the issue. Can you put a link to the forum post in your answer? I want to accept it but I think we should link out to the right post.