# How do I despawn mobs in vanilla Minecraft? (1.8.8)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can someone help me? I spawned something like 10 Ender Dragons using commands but they're lagging my game so hard I can't kill them. Is there a command in vanilla Minecraft to kill all nearby mobs? And before you say /killall or /kill all they don't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Can I Butcher Animals en Masse?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21541/how-can-i-butcher-animals-en-masse)

Comment: @pppery This post is six years old, why are you here

Comment: Because the Stack Exchange network is an encyclopedia in addition to a Q&A site, and old questions are still supposed to be maintained. The better question is why no one noticed the blatant duplication in 2015 and it fell to me now.

Answer (score 4):

In general the easiest way to remove hostile mobs is to switch to Peaceful mode, but I'm not certain that will work with ender dragons.

If it doesn't work or isn't an option, you could place a command block and use the command:

```
/kill @e[type=!Player]
```

This will kill everything other than players, but ideally it should be called from a command block for it to work correctly.

In this case if you only need to kill ender dragons, you can use the command:

```
/kill @e[type=EnderDragon]
```

Comment: type=EnderDragon will just kill the dragons, if you don't want to wipe out all the animals.

Comment: Very true, I was focusing on the question title. I'll add that in.

Comment: How is using a command block any different or better in this situation?

Comment: @ydobonebi There was a point where certain commands/player selectors would only work from inside command blocks. So I usually suggest using a command block, just in case the user is on an older version (Obviously not for the asker of this question, but it may be useful to other people reading this)

Answer (score -1):

you can go into peaceful to despawn the mobs and for the ender dragons that don't despawn in peaceful type /give @p minecraft:diamond_swprd 1 0 {ench:[{id:16,lvl:9999},{id:34,lvl:255},{id:35,lvl:100}],display:{Name:"Ultimate sword",Lore:["supah powered blade!"]}} it kills any mob in one hit