# How do I kill only donkeys with /kill?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trieing to find a way to kill only donkeys in Minecraft. I tried only one thing (/kill @a donkey), didn't work. Does anyone know how to kill donkeys in Minecraft?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Can I Butcher Animals en Masse?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21541/how-can-i-butcher-animals-en-masse)

Answer (score 6):

[Target selectors](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selector_arguments) allow you to specify a `type` argument. You'll also need to use `@e` for entities, rather than `@a` which is only for players.

The following command should work:

```
/kill @e[type=donkey]
```