# How do I kill only sheep with /kill?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need to get rid of a lot of sheep. I've tried to kill them all with `/kill @e[Type=Sheep]` but it doesn't kill them all and my world lags, a lot. I'm on version 1.8.3.

Comment: Why are you in 1.8.3? That version is over 4 years old!

Comment: @FabianRöling probably an old cracked version. Anyways, to answer the question, the command is case-sensitive, which stops it from working (AFAIR).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Can I Butcher Animals en Masse?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21541/how-can-i-butcher-animals-en-masse)

Answer (score -1):

I did a bit of research around the minecraft wiki and did some testing in a 1.8.3 vanilla world. I've never done much with commands before but I still managed to come up with something that only kills sheep.

The command is `/kill @e[name=Sheep]`

Notes

- This is case sensitive so putting 'sheep' instead of 'Sheep' will cause it to fail
- Items will still be dropped when the sheep die
- This kills baby sheep as well as regular sheep
- This command will not kill named sheep

Hope this works out well for you

After a bit more research I got the command you were trying to use to work, the exact command is `/kill @e[type=Sheep]`. This command kills named sheep too so be careful about making them extinct. Looks like 'type' has to be all lower but 'Sheep' has to start with a capital.

Comment: I´m not familiar with commands in 1.8, but `type=sheep` should work there, too, note that it likely is case sensitive, so that may have been the reason why it didn´t work for you.

Comment: Also note that this will only kill sheep on loaded chunks.